# TypeError: add_edge() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weight'

Tags: python, typeerror, networkx

I try to make a PERT graph. So, I tried to put a bool variable "_dirty" that checks whether the graph is deformed. However, the add_egde function does not work properly. Is the code wrong?

My graph code:

```py
class ClassName(nx.MultiDiGraph):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._dirty = True 
        self._critical_path = None

    def add_edge(self, *args):
        """ add one edge """
        self._dirty = True
        super().add_edge(*args)
```

Using add_edge:

```
graph_name.add_edge(1, 2, weight = 35)
```

Error I got:

```
TypeError: add_edge() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weight'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that you only specify to get arguments, not keyword arguments(weight in your case.)

Try adding **kwargs like add_edge(self, *args,**kwargs), and it should be fine.
Also dont forget to update the super after that. :)

Comment: No problem, if that's no problem please mark my answer as one that solves your problem. Thank you!